# query: Remove aggregate function name for header

Tags: google-sheets, sum, label, max, google-query-language

I have simulated joining in google sheets with one =query function per row.  If I put an aggregate function in there, this does not work anymore, since I'll always get two rows at least: 1 for displaying what aggegate function I have, one displaying the result:

```
=QUERY(Departments!B:N;"select N, max(C),max(M), max(J) where N="&A4&" group by N";0)
```

results in

```
            max         max     max 
   21001    27.11.2022  20000   40000
```

even though I have the "headers" set to 0.

this is probably a bug in google sheets - but is there another way to get rid of the max's row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(Departments!B:N;
 "select N,max(C),max(M),max(J) 
  where N="&A4&" 
  group by N"; ); "offset 1"; )
```

or:

```
=QUERY(Departments!B:N;
 "select N,max(C),max(M),max(J) 
  where N="&A4&" 
  group by N 
  label max(C)'',max(M)'',max(J)''"; )
```

Comment: I went with the labeling solution, to avoid double querying (I want to do a lot of queries in a column... labeling is hopefully performing better than querying)

Answer (score 0):

```
=QUERY(Departments!B:N; "select N, max(C) as MaxC, max(M) as MaxM, max(J) as MaxJ where N="&A4&" group by N"; 0)
```

or

```
=PIVOT(Departments!B:N; N; C, M, J; "MaxC", "MaxM", "MaxJ")
```

Comment: in google sheets I tried the ; 0 at the end, for aggregates this did _not_ remove the function name.  Pivot does not seem to be a google sheets thing?